# Can infinite-dimensional vector (or normed) spaces be categorized as countably-infinite-dimensional and uncountably-infinite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

We know that an infinite set $S$ is said to be *countably infinite* if there is a bijective function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to S$. Otherwise, $S$ is said to be *uncountably infinite*.

Now my question is, is there any such categorization discussed in the mathematical literature of infinite-dimensional vector spaces or normed spaces? If so, then what is regarded as the most authoritative reference in this regard?

what important property (or properties) do countably-infinite-dimensional vector (or normed) spaces enjoy that the uncountably-infinite-dimensional ones lack, and vice versa?

Comment: Let me just point out that such a categorization definitely makes sense - the result stating that all bases of a vector space have the same cardinality works even in infinite-dimensional setting (assuming axiom of choice) (but it has to be shown in a different way than for finite-dimensional spaces), so it can't happen that a space has both a countably infinite and uncountably infinite bases.

Answer (score 1):

The basic distinction is that a countable-dimensional normed vector space cannot be Banach; this is a nice exercise. In the normed setting the size of a (Hamel) basis isn't what we really care about anyway. For example, in the setting of Hilbert spaces what really matters is the size of an orthonormal basis, and that can be countable.

In fact there is a unique (up to isomorphism) Hilbert space with a countable orthonormal basis, equivalently a unique Hilbert space which is separable, which is sometimes (more commonly by physicists) just called "the Hilbert space" or just "Hilbert space."

In the vector space setting there's not much to say. A vector space is determined up to isomorphism by its dimension, which can be any cardinal. They all behave pretty much the same, although there's some tricky business about computing the dimension of the dual vector space in general.